# Do you need to add some Typoscript when using flux:grid together with v:content.render?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am attempting to use Fluid templates to render pages. I have created an extension file provider and some page templates which appear to be rendering.

Unfortunately, the content I add to pages is *not* rendering.

I am attempting to follow the [example in the Flux documentation](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/GridViewHelper.html) (Two-column page template and Page Rendering sections).

I have also been reading the [Creating Page Template page in the Fluid documentation](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/page-template.html).

When I do this, it correctly makes the grid layouts available in the TYPO3 backend.

However, when I select one of those layouts for a page, and then add some content, the content is not rendered in the page.

Am I missing a step? For example, is there some Typoscript I need to write here? The documentation appear to be incomplete/unfinished.

I have tried adding the following Typoscript in Configuration/Typoscript/setup.txt:

```
page {
  10 {
    variables {
      left < styles.content.get
      left.select.where = colPos = 0

      right < styles.content.get
      right.select.where = colPos = 1
    }
  }
}
```

But it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the static templates of either `css styled content` or `fluid styled content`?

Comment: Adding the fluid styled content template as an include in my root Typoscript template was exactly what I needed to do, thanks.